# SQL Job Execution Issue in SQL-Server 2012

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-job

I am Executing an SSIS Package in SQL-Server 2012 through SQL-Job. Individual package is getting execute in Visual-Studio and also after releasing it on Service-Catalog (Just for testing). But When I am adding same package without any source or any change, Its execution keep going without any error or end.

Later I got one error message during Job execution from Windows-Log Viewer and error message is as follow:

> Error, [136] Job `Daily Job 2` report: Process 4a94 was invoked
>   by step 1, job 0x04B3B7D6263F2348B84183641 BF86091, but can not be
>   terminated (Reason: Access is denied.)

I have applied settings as below.

[image]

what does this error mean and what solution I can apply`

I am creating the SQL-Job and Package Execution on Server directly.

Comment: Seems that the account running the job does not have enough permissions to access the package, you can either use a different account or grant permissions to the current one

Comment: @Petaflop: what permission I should assign? can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Account running SSIS job does not have enough permission to access source file/folder/package.

You need to give permission for user to access package from filesystem

Comment: Which permission i should assign? I tried many ways of assigning permission to current user. but still same problem.

Comment: first you need to find current SSIS user. After that you need to find physical location of your package. then you need to give permission to that file for the current SSIS user. the permission should be execute permission. However, since we don't know what your SSIS package includes I am unsure whether giving permission to SSIS package itself will be enough or not

Comment: package is having file import logic from same machine folder

Comment: I have Edited my question. could you please check?

Comment: Now SSIS does not see your package. Again different permission issue

Comment: @Sininare: Even I tried blank package execution without any code or connection, Still it shows same issue